# How to call shutdown on an ExecutorService that has been supplied to a CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, spring, executorservice, shutdown, completable-future

I am running a batch job every 15 minutes, where I get records for 5 different events and push them out to an API to eventually go out as Push Notifications on a mobile device.

I am using Java 8, Spring boot application with Quartz scheduler.

I have a service class which reads the different event types from a property file and loops over those and creates 5 different controllers via a Factory to handle each of these 5 events.

My question is where do I call executor.shutdown to shutdown the ExecutorService?

Here is the basic structure of my program:

```
 public class ServiceImpl {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    for (Event event: eventTypes)
        
        
        EventController eventController = eventFactory.createEventController(event);
        eventController.executeTasks(executor);
                
        
    }
}


public interface EventController {
    
    EventBean executeTasks(ExecutorService executor);
    
    EventBean transform1();
    EventBean transform2(); 
}



public class EventController1 implements EventController {



    public EventBean executeTasks(ExecutorService executor) {


        CompletableFuture<List<Event1>> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                        
                //db call 1
                                        
        }, executor);
                
                
        CompletableFuture<EventBean1> combinedFuture = cf1
                .thenCombineAsync(() -> {

                //db call 2, independent from 1, hence called async

        });

        combinedFuture
        .thenApply(e -> transform1())
        .thenApply(e -> transform2())

    }   

}


public class EventController2 implements EventController {



    public EventBean executeTasks(ExecutorService executor) {


        CompletableFuture<List<Event2>> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                        
                //db call 1
                                        
        }, executor);
                
                
        CompletableFuture<EventBean1> combinedFuture = cf1
                .thenCombineAsync(() -> {

                //db call 2, independent from 1, hence called async

        });

        combinedFuture
        .thenApply(e -> transform1())
        .thenApply(e -> transform2())

    }   

}


public class EventController3 implements EventController {



    public EventBean executeTasks(ExecutorService executor) {


        CompletableFuture<List<Event3>> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                        
               //db call 1
                                        
        }, executor);
                
                
        CompletableFuture<EventBean1> combinedFuture = cf1
                .thenCombineAsync(() -> {

                //db call 2, independent from 1, hence called async

        });

        combinedFuture
        .thenApply(e -> transform1())
        .thenApply(e -> transform2())

    }   

}
```

Comment: why do you think you need to call it?

Comment: This is a batch program running every 15 mins and I was worried that if the threads were not garbage collected in a timely fashion, it could accumulate over time.

Comment: but if you shut it down, what do you think will happen next time when you submit a task? not that the GC is a real thing to worry

Comment: It is going to run these on each batch run.

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

So essentially creating a new pool each time.

Comment: did you _try_ this before posting this comment?

Comment: Yes earlier I was not using CompletableFuture, just Future and I was calling shutdown at the end of each batch job run. Now I have reworked the code to use CompletableFuture but not sure of how to shutdown the pool.

Comment: isn't `ServiceImpl` a Spring bean? but anyway, if you simply want to shutDown the executor: `executor.shutDown()`

Comment: In your example, only the first call to `supplyAsync` uses the specified `executor`. The next call to `supplyAsync` doesn’t use it, hence, will use the default executor. The calls to `thenApply` do not use an executor at all, the will be executed by whatever thread the implementation choses. It might be the caller thread or the completer of the previous stage (which would, as said, not be one of the specified executor). So, since this code will never try to submit more jobs to the specified executor than the initial one, you could invoke `shutDown` on it right after the loop.

Comment: But since these methods are supposed to return an instance of `EventBean`, it’s not going to work that way. Post your real code.